# Why does a call on a static method returning null not result in a NullPointerException?

Tags: java

In my opinion calling `getCity()` method will return null, so `null.name` makes no sense, but it works. Both print statements are printed.

```
package javaapplication1;
public class JavaApplication1 {

    static String name = "New york";

    static JavaApplication1 getCity(){
        System.out.println("Getting city");
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( getCity().name );
    }
}
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/rTJup5

Comment: what do you mean by "but it work" ?

Comment: It works as the name is static that does not need any object to call.

Comment: It is neither a good nor a bad question. It is a tricky code that as we read it fast may be misleading. Morale : compiler warnings are designed to be handled.

Comment: According to java language specification a class variable can be
   accessible by with null reference also.<br> 
 We can access the static
   variable through class name as well as object reference.
 - In evaluation of  `getCity().name` first `getCity()` is evaluated and result is discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working as `static String name = "New york";` is static.

Remove the `static`  from it it will throw a `NullPointerException`. Static members do not need an object to call as a static member are class level members. Below code will also work.

```
JavaApplication1 application = null;
System.out.println(application.name);
```

Your `getCity().name` is same as `JavaApplication1.name`In your case compiler will give you a warning like below

> The static field JavaApplication1.name should be accessed in a non-static
>   way

Comment: `application.name` is equivalent to `JavaApplication1.name`.

Answer (score 1):

It works only because you call a static member of the object.

In your case, name is not related to an instance of `JavaApplication1`, it is only related to `JavaApplication1` class. When you call `getCity().name` in reality you call `JavaApplication.name`.

If you remove the `static` modifier before `String name = "New york"` you will get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Have fun!